# C++ Qt / Boost How to hash data by using Bcrypt with the given salt?

Tags: c++, boost

I want to hash given data by using bcrypt such as it implemented in Node.js https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/blob/master/bcrypt.js#L109

I found `bcrypt` library in boost (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/boost/winapi/bcrypt.hpp)
but i didn't find some examples.

Could someone help me with my issue?

Comment: There's no bcrypt library in boost. _["The Boost.WinAPI library is an abstraction layer for Windows API intended to be used internally by other Boost libraries. Boost.WinAPI is not a public library for users of Boost."](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/winapi/doc/html/index.html). If you target Windows only, just use the Windows API. If not, use something like https://forum.qt.io/topic/59403/solved-hash-passwords or [CryptoC++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypto%2B%2B) and many others

Comment: Thanks.
Could you provide an example of hashing password with the given salt by using Windows Api, please?

Comment: I don't think I will. But you can help yourself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/creating-a-hash-with-cng